# Linear Regression -- Regularization, shrinkage

Tags: regression, regularization

Regularization reduces the magnitudes of the regression coefficients. I read that this helps reduce the variance of the model. Why exactly do smaller values of the coefficients lead to a lower variance model?

Comment: There's a logical fallacy in the formulation of this question: it is *regularization* that reduces the variance, not the fact that many coefficients become smaller.  In fact, regularization can (and often does) *increase* the magnitudes of some coefficients.

Comment: I thought it is also called shrinkage for the same reason -- that it shrinks the coefficients to smaller values.

Comment: @whuber here is a statement from one of the text books on regression. "shrinkage methods -- techniques that constrains or regularize the coefficient estimates or equivalently that shrinks the coefficient estimates towards zero.

Comment: (quotation slightly paraphrased to suit the context here -- but thats the message).

Comment: Shrinkage methods like ridge regression and the lasso shrink some norm of the entire $\beta$ vector. It is possible that the norm of the entire vector could be reduced yet some particular coefficients increase.